# Increment a data value if another row field already exists with same value

Tags: mysql

Consider I have 3 columns Product Name, Product ID and Inventory ID. When i insert a new product by product name, if it doesn't exist it should show inventory ID as product001. But if the product already exists it should increment the value of the existing inventory ID by one(product002). How should I write a SQL query for this?
This is what i have so far.

```
INSERT
INTO    product (productname, productID, inventoryID)
VALUES  ("Book", 3, (CONCAT(MID(productname,1,2),'-',1)))
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  inventoryID = CONCAT(MID(productname,1,2),'-',((SELECT 
SUBSTRING(inventoryID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', inventoryID), 
LEN(inventoryID)) + 1)));
```